# Reach the subcategory from the Product model (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am trying to reach the last laravel model from the first one with eloquent relationships. How can I reach the Subcategory directly from Product?

The 3 Models I have:

**Product** (id, category_id, etc..)

```
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
    }
```

**Category** (id, name)

```
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'category_id');
    }

    public function sub_categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\SubCategory', 'category_id');
    }
```

**SubCategory** (id, category_id, name)

```
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
    }
```

I would've assumed I could reach it with

```
Product::find(1)->categories->sub_categories;
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0):

read this [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

**Product**

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function SubCategory()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Category', 'App\SubCategory');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Addition add the `subCategories` method on `Product` model and also a product is belongs to a category not categories
and also always try to use camel case for the methods (subCategories)

replace your code with this

**Product:**

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
}

public function subCategories()
{
    return $this->category()->subCategories;
}
```

**Category:**

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'category_id');
}

public function subCategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\SubCategory', 'category_id');
}
```

**SubCategory:**

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
}
```

finally use this to get the subcategories

```
Product::find(1)->subCategories;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Product::find(1)->categories` is an `array`. You will have to loop it to get the subcategory of each category. See below

```html
$categories = Product::find(1)->categories;
foreach ($categories as $category {
 //Get subcategories for each category
 dump($category->sub_categories);
}
```